# Array of structures or structure of array in C

Tags: c, arrays, structure

Which one is the fastest/least memory consuming option of these two:

```
struct {
int index;
char string[10];
} a[10];
```

or

```
struct {
int index[10];
char string[10][10];
} a;
```

The first one is clearly easier to use and implement. I also have to mention I will dynamically allocate them. But which one will run faster or be least time consuming?

Thank you!

Comment: There may be minuscule differences which depend on information not provided in the question (e.g. what C implementation you use, including what compiler options, and more importantly what you actually do with the structure). Speed is not a property of C structs. The most common thing I can think of is that the former is going to be a bit bigger on a lot of implementations, perhaps 160 bytes vs 140. Good luck actually detecting any performance difference, though.

Comment: Why use an array of indexes in the second structure?  If you want to address a particular element of string then you just need to know the range of the array.  Would it not be simpler to store the size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct {
    int index;
    char string[10];
} a[10];
```

will introduce padding for each `a[]` item.

The second solution will introduce padding only once.

If you are going to allocate a large number of items in `a[]` then you will pay the price of having a larger domain to cover (not to mention the additional dereferencing).

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with premature optimization. Use the one easier to understand/maintain. Since this is C, performance difference will barely be noticeable.

Comment: +1 for the first two sentences, but -1 for the last one. As long as the number of items is fixed at 10, this won't be noticeable in any language, but when this number grows big, locality-of-reference effects come into play so performance depends strongly on the task.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd would probably be smaller memory-wise simply because sizeof struct above is 8, not 5 because of padding (provided that int is 32-bit).

As for which is faster, I'd say it would depend on what you're doing; the 2nd is a typical example of data-oriented design (not to be confused with data-driven design). Please see this article: http://gamesfromwithin.com/data-oriented-design

EDIT: That said, I agree with Milan here (at the other answer) -- don't bother optimizing prematurely, or at all. Both are fast enough; I didn't emphasize this earlier because I figured you might need it for an embedded system, where this could matter.